# I'm stuck on the jewel store heist!

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v, xbox-one

In GTA V on the Xbox One, I just did the 'casing the jewel store' mission with Lester Crest, and I chose the people I was going to do the heist with, but I don't know what to do next.

Is Lester going to call me? Should I go somewhere? When I call Lester he doesn't answer, and there's nothing new on my map. I don't know how to proceed to the next part of this mission.

Answer (score 2):

You will receive a call from Lester that unlocks the setup missions. If you choose the smart option, then you simply need to wait for the call. If you choose the loud option, then you'll need to complete the mission, Daddy's Little Girl, which can be triggered by Michael at Michael's house.

Comment: Thank you! I chose the smart option, so there's nothing left to do but wait I guess..